# Docker does not really remove the images

Tags: docker

I've encountered a peculiar issue with Docker where it appears that images are not entirely removed, even after I've explicitly deleted them. Here's what's happening:

I build an image using a Dockerfile.
I realize I'm not satisfied with the image, so I attempt to remove it using `docker image rm <image_id>`.
The image is seemingly removed, as it no longer appears in the list when I run `docker images`.
However, when I try to build the same Dockerfile again, without making any changes, Docker inexplicably builds the image almost instantly, suggesting that the previous image or its layers are somehow persisting in the background.

I want to emphasize that I've indeed deleted the previous image using `docker image rm <image_id>`, and only the base image (`python:3.9-slim-bookworm`) remains.

What could be causing this behavior, and how can I ensure that Docker completely removes all traces of an image so that I can start fresh with a clean slate?

I know I can use `--no-cache` to force Docker to rebuild everything, but I'm curious about why this is happening in the first place.

```
Client:
 Version:           20.10.24+dfsg1
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.19.8
 Git commit:        297e128
 Built:             Thu May 18 08:38:34 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.24+dfsg1
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.19.8
  Git commit:       5d6db84
  Built:            Thu May 18 08:38:34 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.20~ds1
  GitCommit:        1.6.20~ds1-1+b1
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.5+ds1
  GitCommit:        1.1.5+ds1-1+b1
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:
```

Comment: The build cache is distinct from the local image repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you "build" a Docker image for the first time, it "caches" some data so that it doesn't have to execute those the next time. It's quite intended behavior and for good reasons. When you "remove" an image, indeed it's deleted from the system, but the "caches" stay behind (again - for good reasons). When you "rebuild" an image, it's built from scratch, but it uses those left-behind "caches" to speed things up. That's the reason Docker caches the "layers" of the images. You can get rid of "all" caches by running [`docker system prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) command.

You don't have to do that, as it's not necessary to remove caches every now and then, as Docker does that intentionally to boost performance. When you build an image, it's indeed built from scratch (not from "clean slate" as you referred).

Imagine when you build an image which takes several minutes and Docker builds it every time from "clean slate"...  You'd be broke paying for compute hours of CI/CD runners...